# Как добавить RecyclerView на Фрагмент в NavigationDrawer Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, список

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на какую любо кнопку в NavigationDrawer-е открылась фрагмент со списками (с RecyclerView). Фрагмент уже создал осталось создать список.

**Код MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new Message_Fragment()).commit();
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_message);}
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_message:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new Message_Fragment()).commit();
        break;
        case R.id.nav_chat:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new Chat_Fragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new Profile_Fragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new Settings_Fragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new Send_Fragment()).commit();
            break;

    }
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
    super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Код Message_Fragment.java**

```
public class Message_Fragment extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: так в чем проблема? в xml recyclerview добавить?

Comment: Нет проблема в том, что не могу прописать на сам фрагмент. Вылетают ошибки. Но сейчас я не об этом. просто научите как правильно прописать код для RecyclerView на самом фрагменте (в xml понятно).

Comment: без кода мы вам ничем помочь не можем

Comment: Добавил коды, кроме xml файла. Посмотрите. Проект чистый.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Все довольно просто, у вас есть файл разметки `fragment_one`. Перейдите на него и добавьте в xml разметку виджет списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    tools:context=".bla_bla_bla">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

дальше перейдите в фрагмент и инициализируйте данный список:

```
val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
val list:RecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
```

весь код `onCreate()` будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false)
            val list:RecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
            return rootView
    }
```

Код написан на Kotlin но принцип я думаю будет понятен. Дальше добавляем в список данные и отображаем. [Вот](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) хорошая статья по вашему вопросу и [вот](https://metanit.com/java/android/5.11.php).